# Android JsonObject auto-updating it's parent

Tags: json

I define a new JSonObject and getting it's content from another JsonArray in my app.. But during the code flow, jsonArray is unwillingly changing whenever the jsonObject changes..

The jsonArray is static, can this be a cause? But I need it static for other purposes..

How can I just change the jsonObject without changing jsonArray? 
Thanks in advance..

```
public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity{
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        jsonArray=OtherActivity.jArray; //static array from other activity
        jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        try {
            if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).has(TAG)) {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getJSONObject(TAG);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {            e.printStackTrace();        }


    //.....

    jsonObject.put("sth","someValue");  //jsonArray also changing as soon as jsonObject changes

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are assigning it to the jsonArray object.

```
jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getJSONObject(TAG);
```

You should clone the object into the new JsonObject. You can do something like this....

```
JsonObject temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getJSONObject(TAG);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(temp, JSONObject.getNames(temp));
```